# How to access google sheets without authentication?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have watched the following video where a demo is given about accessing google sheets without authentication:-

https://youtu.be/t6WSY9D_ORQ?list=LL

As per the video I am unable to access my google sheet in pandas with the following code:-

```
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = "my_sheet_id"
r = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/export?format=csv".format(sheet_id)
df = pd.read_csv(r)
df.head()
```

The exception I get is:-

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

This same code works for the following google sheet which is public:-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9p3nqTf9fBx8I4lb3WMC_K0BLaIU8Z-7kj7MVani3U/edit?usp=sharing
where the `sheet_id = "1x9p3nqTf9fBx8I4lb3WMC_K0BLaIU8Z-7kj7MVani3U"`

Do I need to add some headers/parameters for this to work?

Comment: I don't think you can access sheets that are not public without authentication.

Comment: If the same code works for the public sheet you mention, then doesn't the problem have to be that either the sheet you want to access isn't public or the URL you're using to access it is wrong?  Does the same URL your code is trying to access bring up the sheet without authentication when you paste it into your browser's address bar?  If the point is that you shouldn't have to authenticate, then I can't think what else you'd need to put in the headers, and otherwise, the URL is whatever the URL is.  If it works in your browser, it ought to work in your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modifying the endpoint as follows? This endpoint can be seen at `exportLinks` of the method of "Files: get" in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

#### From:

```
r = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/export?format=csv".format(sheet_id)
```

#### To:

```
r = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={}&exportFormat=csv".format(sheet_id)
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your sample Spreadsheet, the data could be retrieved. In this case, the Spreadsheet is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)